# wxPython and ARCGIS

Tags: wxpython, arcgis, arcpy

I am working on an Desktop application built with wx Python. I would like the application to visualize maps(shapefiles) like a GIS software and provide interactions with the map. I was looking through arcpy and arcgisscripting but I am not sure if it help me render the shapefile on the Panel. Please do let me know if it is possible?

Comment: You may need to copy/paste the business logic from your application into an add-in or ICommand/ITool for ArcGIS Explorer or ArcMap.  This is because ArcGIS has its own rendering engine that will let you display a shapefile directly.  You can even set up symbology like attribute based symbols for each point, line and polygon feature.  Example: show wires with "above ground" attribute as a solid line and show wires with "underground" attribute as a dotted line.

Answer (score 0):

There is an application created with wxPython for GIS here: http://thuban.intevation.org/

There's also one for GRASS: http://grass.osgeo.org/wiki/WxPython-based_GUI_for_GRASS

You can probably use those as starting places at least.

Comment: Im am looking using ARCGIS which is widely used. Using arcpy within ARCGIS environment works fine. But if i try to import i get com errors. Let me know if there is a work around for this

Answer (score 0):

ArcGIS has it's own rendering engine.  You would need to create an ArcPy tool or script or add-in for something like ArcGIS Explorer or the paid version ArcMap.  You could also look into making an ArcPy tool, script, or add-in for their ArcGIS Runtime.